# Cheap way of attaching canning jars to a concrete wall?

Tags: concrete, walls, glass

Is there a cheap way of securely attaching a small glass Mason jar (like the one below) filled with water to a concrete wall? The jar doesn't have a top and it doesn't have a handle.

I'll be using it to decorate the wall: I'll fill the jar with water, put some plant or some flower in it, and just "stick" it to the wall.

[image]

Comment: Permanently attaching, or something frequently removed and re-attached? You can run a wire around the neck of the bottle and attach that to the wall with a fastener. Provide a little more detail and someone will come along with a better answer.

Comment: Does it need to be installed vertically?  Or could you screw a lid onto the wall then screw the jar onto that?

Comment: I use velcro strips to hold spice jars to a plank; no visible connectors. The name brand stuff can hold a lot of weight, especially as shear. I can see rubber bands and a hook/command working as well.

Comment: What sort of concrete wall? The term implies poured, solid concrete. What modification to the wall is allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you will be putting water and flowers in them you will need to be able to take them down and clean them.

I would make some kind of wire cage to hold them, use some malleable wire and cover with chicken wire or ??,  mount the cage on the wall and then place the jar inside.

[image: simple cage]

Or ( ***My choice*** ) buy something [like these light protectors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CKPVK9L) and mount them on the wall ( *large opening up* ) with some thin aluminum or copper strips. ( *if money was not an issue i would make some black iron pipe holders to mount these to.* )

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a hose clamp:

[image: Hose clamp]

Find one large enough to fit around the jar (bigger is better). Being mindful of how the clamp closes so you don't interfere with that operation, you could use a small screw through the slats of the clamp into the wall or a board.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you could attach the jar and ring assembly to a nice piece of barnwood or something if you're going arty, and then attach the board to concrete through any number of methods- tapcon screws, 3M adhesive, etc.

This would also allow you to remove the jar for cleaning or refill by simply expanding the ring's closure to remove the jar

Answer (score 0):

Hooks higher up the wall (maybe on one batten), and some decorative string, and an ancient knot.

Romans used it to suspend jars of olive oil to avoid breakages in slave galleys when the seas were rough, and called it the Amphora Knot.

Bootleggers during prohibition used it for bourbon when the cops chased them, and called it the Jug Knot.

In the UK, it is a Bottle Knot, and was used in shipyards and mines to smuggle something warming into the workplace, slung inside your coat so your pocket did not bulge. Sailors used it on their kit-bags, so it is also the Bag Knot.

Nice touch is that it can be tied in the middle of a length of rope -- no need for ends. So you can tie up a row of containers with a single piece of rope, which hangs between them.